# LXC - Can't access package manager from linux container

Tags: package-managers, lxc, linux-containers, lxd, fedora-27

I have LXD installed on a fedora 27 machine. I configured it a while ago, and it has worked fine long enough that I forgot how I set everything up. I just tried to create a new container and it creates successfully, but I can't get it to access the package manager. I vaguely remember this being a problem when I created my other containers back when I installed everything, but I can't remember how I fixed it. As of now, my other old containers work fine, and have access to the package manager, and everything works fine. But when I create a new container, it acts as though the package manager doesn't exist.

How do I install the package manager to a new Linux Container using LXD?

Thanks,

-Yurelle

```
[root@neon ~]# lxc launch images:fedora/27 myThing
Creating myThing
Starting myThing
[root@neon ~]# lxc exec myThing bash
[root@myThing ~]# apt
bash: apt: command not found
[root@myThing ~]# apt-get
bash: apt-get: command not found
[root@myThing ~]# yum
bash: yum: command not found
[root@myThing ~]# rpm
RPM version 4.14.1
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc.
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL

Usage: rpm [-afgpcdLAlsiv?] [-a|--all] [-f|--file] [-g|--group] [-p|--package] [--pkgid] [--hdrid] [--triggeredby] [--whatrequires] [--whatprovides] [--whatrecommends]
        [--whatsuggests] [--whatsupplements] [--whatenhances] [--nomanifest] [-c|--configfiles] [-d|--docfiles] [-L|--licensefiles] [-A|--artifactfiles] [--dump] [-l|--list]
        [--queryformat=QUERYFORMAT] [-s|--state] [--nofiledigest] [--nofiles] [--nodeps] [--noscript] [--allfiles] [--allmatches] [--badreloc] [-e|--erase=<package>+]
        [--excludedocs] [--excludepath=<path>] [--force] [-F|--freshen=<packagefile>+] [-h|--hash] [--ignorearch] [--ignoreos] [--ignoresize] [-i|--install] [--justdb]
        [--nodeps] [--nofiledigest] [--nocontexts] [--nocaps] [--noorder] [--noscripts] [--notriggers] [--oldpackage] [--percent] [--prefix=<dir>] [--relocate=<old>=<new>]
        [--replacefiles] [--replacepkgs] [--test] [-U|--upgrade=<packagefile>+] [--reinstall=<packagefile>+] [-D|--define='MACRO EXPR'] [--undefine=MACRO] [-E|--eval='EXPR']
        [--target=CPU-VENDOR-OS] [--macros=<FILE:...>] [--noplugins] [--nodigest] [--nosignature] [--rcfile=<FILE:...>] [-r|--root=ROOT] [--dbpath=DIRECTORY] [--querytags]
        [--showrc] [--quiet] [-v|--verbose] [--version] [-?|--help] [--usage] [--scripts] [--setperms] [--setugids] [--conflicts] [--obsoletes] [--provides] [--requires]
        [--recommends] [--suggests] [--supplements] [--enhances] [--info] [--changelog] [--changes] [--xml] [--triggers] [--filetriggers] [--last] [--dupes] [--filesbypkg]
        [--fileclass] [--filecolor] [--fileprovide] [--filerequire] [--filecaps]
[root@myThing ~]# exit
exit
[root@neon ~]# lxc info myThing
Name: myThing
Remote: unix://
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2018/06/09 22:24 UTC
Status: Running
Type: persistent
Profiles: default
Pid: 32310
Ips:
  eth0: inet    10.0.1.234      veth62EL09
  eth0: inet6   fe80::216:3eff:fe13:5c02        veth62EL09
  lo:   inet    127.0.0.1
  lo:   inet6   ::1
Resources:
  Processes: 7
  Disk usage:
    root: 7.71MB
  CPU usage:
    CPU usage (in seconds): 0
  Memory usage:
    Memory (current): 37.62MB
    Memory (peak): 39.65MB
  Network usage:
    eth0:
      Bytes received: 10.46kB
      Bytes sent: 3.68kB
      Packets received: 77
      Packets sent: 36
    lo:
      Bytes received: 510B
      Bytes sent: 510B
      Packets received: 6
      Packets sent: 6
[root@neon ~]#
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about programming.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Where is the correct place to post this question? I searched the whole stack exchange site tree for "LXC" and found a few questions about it all over the place. The most where on here, so I assumed this was the right child site to post it. https://stackexchange.com/search?q=lxc

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ or for LXC/LXD specific issues https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm an idiot, the Fedora image defaults to using the DNF package manager. So, either use that, or use it to install yum:

```
[root@neon ~]# lxc launch images:fedora/27 myThing
Creating myThing
Starting myThing
[root@neon ~]# lxc exec myThing bash
[root@myThing ~]# dnf update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:42:05 ago on Sat Jun  9 22:24:14 2018.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@myThing ~]# dnf install yum
Last metadata expiration check: 0:42:12 ago on Sat Jun  9 22:24:14 2018.
Dependencies resolved.
...
```